# Change the elements displayed on the RSS Feed

Tags: menu-item, system-plugin, rss

I turned on the 'Show Feed Link' located in the 'Integration' tab of a Menu item which then adds the following in the document head:

```
  <link href="/link?format=feed&amp;type=rss" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" />
  <link href="/link?format=feed&amp;type=atom" rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 1.0" />
```

Clicking on either takes to either a RSS or ATOM feed which by default shows 5 latest Article. Here is a sample output:

```
<channel>
    <title>Feed Title</title>
    <description>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </description>
    <link>http://www.domain.com/link</link>
    <lastBuildDate>Wed, 16 Dec 2015 13:49:23 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <generator>Joomla! - Open Source Content Management</generator>
    <atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://www.domain.com/link?format=feed&amp;type=rss" />
    <language>en-gb</language>
    <managingEditor>Editor</managingEditor>
    <item>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <link>http://www.domain.com/link/item-1</link>
        <guid isPermaLink="true">http://www.domain.com/link/item-1</guid>
        <description>
            <![CDATA[HTML Content]]></description>
        <author>Author Name</author>
        <category>Category</category>
        <pubDate>Thu, 28 May 2015 09:17:02 +0000</pubDate>
    </item>
</channel>
```

I am trying to modify what is outputted (remove a few elements) but I can't find any settings in the Global Configuration except for number of Feed Items. Is there a way to do it in the backend configuration?

I am also trying to find out where is the code that generates this. I looked in the plugins directory but could not find anything that may generate the above code when the 'Show Feed Link' is selected in the Menu Item 'Integration' Tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the file that generates the feeds is located at:

> /libraries/joomla/document/feed/renderer

****Joomla 3.x***

But its a core file - so never change that.

You are able to assign a feed module to each categorie for example and then change it via overrides.